# error while running cap.sniff(), live packets pyshark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyshark

while running the cap.sniff(timeout=20),pyshark in python,
i got the following error`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\capture.py", line 132, in load_packets
    self.apply_on_packets(keep_packet, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\capture.py", line 247, in apply_on_packets
    return self.eventloop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 362, in wait_for
    raise futures.TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError`

what is this error about and how can i solve it to run my capturing successfull

Answer (score 0):

The error given is a `TimeoutError`, so that probably means that timeout that you set is too low. If the the task takes longer than the timeout (in seconds), it will cause a `TimeoutError`.

To fix this, you need to set a higher timeout. Try `cap.sniff(timeout=50)` to see if 50 seconds is long enough. You should try some different timeouts to see how long you need.

Comment: i have tried 50,60,70,90,100,150 still the same error

Comment: i have tried 50,60,70,90,100,150 also 500 still the same error

Comment: @user3306040 does it wait 70 seconds before the error happens if you use 70 for the timeout? (Or whatever number you try?)

Comment: it waits for that amount of time. and now after the error it is showing ' TShark seems to have crashed (retcode: 1). Try rerunning in debug mode [ capture_obj.set_debug() ] or try updating tshark.'
i tried pip install tshark but got this on
'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tshark (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tshark'

Comment: @user3306040 what happens if you do `cap.set_debug()` before the `cap.sniff` line? See if there is anything special printed to the console.

Comment: when run with cap=pyshark.LiveCapture(output_file='p.pcap')
error :---- dumpcap: There is no interface with that adapter index
and when interface is specified cap=pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='wlan0',output_file='p.pcap')
  error----
Capturing on 'wlan0'
dumpcap: The capture session could not be initiated on interface 'wlan0' (Error opening adapter: The system cannot find the device specified. (20)).

Please check that "wlan0" is the proper interface.

Comment: is there problem with my system